# Why do the voting buttons appear on your own posts?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, design, upvotes

I find it strange that the upvote/downvote links on your own post are clickable. Since this action is illegal why not deactivate the link (make it non clickable).

Currently if you click on the upvote/downvote buttons it says "You are not allowed to upvote/downvote your own post".

I am not nitpicking. Just curious to know if there were other design considerations.

**EDIT:**  The posts that other members have pointed out are all talking about removal of the upvote/downvote links. I am trying to make a case for it being deactivated (un-clickable). Have indicated the same in the comments.

Comment: This is actually asked and answered in non-Meta over on UX: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/53986/40970

Comment: You can use [this script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12708/158100) to feel how the site works without them...

Comment: Why do you click on it?

Comment: @rene i don't mind seeing the upvote/downvote link for your own post. For reasons described in the links pointed out by jonrsharpe and you , it makes perfect sense to have them there. But it shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: @klenium i am greedy for rep points :)

Comment: @klenium because they were there.  Also I thought my post was especially good.

Comment: @Twister Yeah, I bet everyone have tried that at least once. :D

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName: The previous one asked for removal, this one carefully (and even successfully) avoided that and instead asked for rationale. I'm not saying either one is *better* than the other, just that people justifiably disagreed with the feature-request but are happy to explain.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName also this one has better grammar.